# Restore previous vim window height

Tags: vim

Many windows in vim can are opened in some predefined layouts (e.g. `copen` or `:Gstatus`). However, further layout changes will disrupt original widow height. I often end up with windows of height `1` or `2` making them almost unusable.

How can I set size to value it previously had with single command for any resized window? I should be able to do it for all windows and get original layout provided the same windows are visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can `:set` minimal hard window limits with `'winminheight'` and `'winminwidth'`. Also, `winrestcmd()` returns a sequence of commands that restore the current window layout.